# É possível criar uma 'classe abstrata' em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, classes, orientação-a-objetos, classes-abstratas

Ao criar uma classe em Javascript cujos atributos e métodos são todos estáticos (por exemplo, para o armazenamento de configurações predefinidas para um jogo), eu gostaria de saber se é possível definir a classe como abstrata de forma similar ao que pode ser realizado em outras linguagens (em que a cláusula '*abstract*' está disponível ou em que se pode simplesmente definir o construtor como protegido).

Em outras palavras: considerando [este exemplo disponível no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luigivieira/yrJ5x/2/), é possível impedir a construção de instâncias da classe 'StaticTest' (na linha 36)? Se o construtor (linha 7) não for definido, o código não executa (gerando a exceção "Uncaught ReferenceError: StaticTest is not defined").

```js
// INICIO - Apenas para evitar poluir o espaço global
(function(){

    /**
     * Construtor da classe (é realmente necessário?).
     */
    var AbstractTest = function() {
    };

    /**
     * Atributo com o texto de teste.
     */
    AbstractTest.Attribute = "O atributo diz: Olá Planeta!";

    /**
     * Método que retorna o texto do teste.
     * @return String com o texto de teste.
     */
    AbstractTest.Method = function() {
        return "O método diz: Olá Mundo!";
    }

    // Atribui a classe ao escopo global 'window'
    window.AbstractTest = AbstractTest;

// FIM - Apenas para evitar poluir o espaço global
}());

/**
 * Função de teste de instanciação.
 * @return String com o texto de teste de uma instância criada.
 */
window.testInstantiation = function() {

    // A dúvida é sobre a possibilidade de impedir a execução dessa linha:
    var oTest = new AbstractTest();

    oTest.Attribute = "O atributo na nova instância diz: Olá Brasil!";
    return oTest.Attribute + " e " + AbstractTest.Attribute;
}
```

Observação: a pergunta é apenas uma curiosidade sobre as características da linguagem; não que a possibilidade de instanciação da classe seja necessariamente um problema.

EDIT: Alterado para corrigir e usar o termo "abstrato" no lugar de "estático".

Comment: +1 porque é uma boa pergunta! Porém, vou acrescentar uma resposta para definir alguns conceitos que estão misturados na pergunta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Em JavaScript não há classes, propriedades ou métodos estáticos. O mais próximo disso são propriedades e métodos atribuídos diretamente a um construtor (como você fez), ou um simples objeto literal.

Se você usar um objeto literal para definir `StaticTest`, então `new StaticTest()` irá gerar um TypeError. É uma maneira de resolver o problema (com `try..catch` em torno da linha que gera a exceção).

Outra maneira é alterar o retorno do construtor. Não entendi exatamente o que você quer no teste, mas é possível retornar o próprio objeto `StaticTest`, ou outro objeto qualquer:

```js
var StaticTest = function() {
    // return StaticTest;
    // ou
    // return {};
};
```

Mas cuidado: se você tentar retornar um valor que não é objeto (como `false`), o construtor vai retornar `this`, ou seja, a instância recém-criada.

---

Considerando sua edição que troca "estática" por "abstrata", acho que a melhor saída seria mesmo usar um objeto literal, já que a intenção é evitar a instanciação:

```js
var StaticTest = {
    attribute: "O atributo diz: Olá Planeta!",
    method: function(){}
    // etc.
};
```

Assim, `StaticTest` geraria uma exceção, que você pode capturar com `try..catch`:

```js
try {
    new StaticTest();
} catch(e) {
    // trate a exceção aqui
}
```

Comment: Retornar o próprio `StaticTest` é uma boa maneira de simular um *singleton*. Para simular uma classe abstrata (i.e. não instanciável), talvez o ideal seria lançar uma exceção no construtor. Isso não impede de fato que uma herança ocorra, como detalhei [na minha resposta](http://br.stackoverflow.com/questions/1920/e-possivel-criar-uma-classe-estatica-em-javascript/1929#1929), mas creio que está próximo do que o OP deseja (faltando só a imutabilidade). P.S. +1 pelo "se você tentar retornar um valor que não é objeto (...) vai retornar `this`", não sabia desse detalhe, fácil passar despercebido...

Comment: Várias respostas bacanas (e bem difícil escolher uma), mas eu escolhi essa pela sugestão simples e direta de usar um objeto literal indicando que gera um TypeError (e, no final, é a mesma conclusão das demais respostas). :) Obrigado a todos!

Answer (score 10):

É possível criar um **objeto imutável** em JavaScript através do método [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze), e uma **referência imutável** através do método [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```javascript
// Atribui a classe ao escopo global 'window'
Object.freeze(StaticTest);
Object.defineProperty(window, "StaticTest", { 
    value:StaticTest,
    configurable:false,
    writable:false
});

// Todas essas tentativas vão falhar silenciosamente:
// (ou lançar uma exceção, se o modo "strict" estiver ativado)
StaticTest = outroObjeto;
window.StaticTest = outroObjeto;
StaticTest.StaticAttribute = outroValor;
delete StaticTest.StaticAttribute;
```

Quanto a **impedir que um objeto seja herdado**, não conheço nenhum meio de se fazer isso, e creio que não seja possível de todo.

### OO Clássica vs. Prototípica

Repare que você perguntou sobre **classes**, mas dei minha resposta falando apenas de **objetos**. Por que? Simplesmente porque, estritamente falando, JavaScript **não possui o conceito de "classes"**.

Na orientação por objetos clássica, utilizada pela grande maioria das linguagens que segue esse paradigma, classes e objetos (ou instâncias) são conceitos distintos: a classe define a "estrutura" e "comportamento" de seus objetos, e cada objeto pertence a uma única classe. Classe herda de classe, de modo que as instâncias da classe específica tenham estrutura e comportamento semelhantes às instâncias da classe geral.

Na OO prototípica, existem apenas objetos. Um objeto define sua própria estrutura e comportamento, de modo independente dos demais. Para reutilizar essas características em outros objetos, estes herdam **diretamente** do objeto existente (aqui chamado **protótipo**), modificando o que quiser e mantendo (compartilhando) o restante. Não existem classes, apenas **funções construtoras**.

### Herança em JavaScript

Por razões históricas, embora conceitualmente JavaScript seja uma linguagem que segue a OO prototípica, a sintaxe dela tenta "esconder" o fato - tornando-a mais parecida um pouco com a clássica. O resultado é uma "salada", como exemplificarei a seguir:

```javascript
// Objeto simples: sem classe, sem construtor
var obj = {
    atributo:"planeta",
    metodo:function() {
        return "Olá, " + this.atributo + "!";
    }
}

// Construindo um objeto que herda de "obj"
function herdarDeObj() { }
herdarDeObj.prototype = obj;

var obj2 = new herdarDeObj();
alert(obj2.metodo()); // "Olá, planeta!"
obj2.atributo = "mundo";
alert(obj2.metodo()); // "Olá, mundo!"

alert( obj.isPrototypeOf(obj2) ); // true
alert( obj === Object.getPrototypeOf(obj2) ); // true

// Sintaxe confusa
alert( obj === obj2.prototype ); // false
alert( obj2.prototype ); // undefined

alert( obj === herdarDeObj.prototype ); // true
alert( obj === Object.getPrototypeOf(herdarDeObj) ); // false
alert( Object.getPrototypeOf(herdarDeObj) ); // function Empty() {}
                                             // (varia conforme o browser)

alert( obj2 instanceof obj ); // false
alert( obj2 instanceof herdarDeObj ); // true
herdarDeObj.foo = "bar";
alert( obj2.foo ); // undefined
obj.foo = "baz";
alert( obj2.foo ); // "baz"
```

Como você pode ver, temos dois objetos `obj` e `obj2` em que o segundo herda do primeiro (ou: o primeiro é protótipo do segundo). Entretanto, JavaScript "esconde" essa relação simples, forçando-nos a criar um método construtor, atribuir-lhe a propriedade `prototype` e invocá-lo através da palavra-chave `new`.

Mas note que `obj` **não é** protótipo de `herdarDeObj` - ele é protótipo **dos objetos construídos** através do comando `new herdarDeObj()`. O construtor é uma função normal, tanto é que seu protótipo é a "função vazia".

Provavelmente devido a esse fato (do construtor definir tudo a respeito do objeto - tanto os atributos iniciais, colocados no corpo do construtor através de `this.atr = val`, quanto o protótipo, aquele de quem o objeto vai herdar) as pessoas confundem-o com a "classe" do objeto. E pela conveniência que esse método construtor oferece, raramente alguém usa [explicitamente] a herança prototípica na prática, tanto é que há planos para se introduzir os conceitos da OO clássica nas versões futuras de JavaScript. Talvez algum dia, isso que você pergunta seja de fato possível.

### Conclusão

Como não existem classes em JavaScript, não faz sentido falar em "classes estáticas" (nem mesmo "atributos estáticos" ou "atributos de classe"). Se você quer expor uma coleção de atributos e métodos por meio de um determinado nome, o mais natural é fazer isso usando um objeto simples:

```javascript
window.StaticTest = {
    StaticAttribute:"O atributo estático diz: Olá Planeta!",
    StaticMethod:function() {
        return "O método estático diz: Olá Mundo!";
    }
};
```

Você pode tornar o objeto e a referência imutáveis, como já expliquei, mas não pode impedir outros objeto de herdarem dele: qualquer um pode criar uma nova função construtora, atribuir `StaticTest` como seu `prototype` e chamar essa função - produzindo objetos que herdam de `StaticTest`.

Comment: Talvez eu não tenha me explicado corretamente, mas a ideia da pergunta é saber se existe uma forma de impedir a execução do "new" (ou seja, impedir a instanciação de novos objetos). Ainda assim, +1 pelas informações sobre como torná-lo imutável. :)

Comment: Outra coisa: uma classe abstrata (em Java, por exemplo) não impede sua herança. Quando eu fiz a pergunta, não tinha essa preocupação em mente também. Mas, novamente, valeu pelas explicações detalhadas.

Comment: @LuizVieira para impedir a execução do "new" creio que o melhor que se pode fazer é lançar uma exceção no construtor se a instância "singleton" já existir. E é fácil herdar do singleton, como explicado na resposta, então se isso não é uma preocupação pra você, tanto melhor!

Comment: Neste caso, usar um objeto literal ou lançar uma exceção no construtor dá na mesma (`new MeuLiteral` também lança exceção, pois o objeto não é uma função).

Answer (score 8):

Há uma séria confusão aqui sobre conceitos de classes e membros (atributos) na pergunta.

## Atributos estáticos

São aqueles que, independentemente da instância da classe/função utilizada, retornam o mesmo valor ou mesma instância de objeto.

O melhor exemplo disso em Javascript é o uso do prototype, como podemos ver na resposta do @mgibsonbr.

## Objetos imutáveis, invariantes ou constantes

Não podemos confundir *estático* com *imutável*. Em Java, por exemplo, um atributo ou variável imutável é declarado com `final` e não com `static`.

Em javascript, parece que a melhor opção é o `Object.freeze`, como podemos ver na resposta do @mgibsonbr.

## Visibilidade

Foi citado na pergunta a questão de impedir a instanciação externa da classe. Em linguagens como Java, isso é obtido criando um construtor `private`. Veja, novamente, que isso não tem a ver com os conceitos de *estático* ou *imutável*.

## Conclusão

Para alcançar seu objetivo, usar uma configuração única, minha sugestão é simplesmente usar uma variável global.

Existem algumas técnicas mais avançadas de como implementar o padrão de projeto Singleton em Javascript ([aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635800/javascript-best-singleton-pattern), [aqui](http://kaijaeger.com/articles/the-singleton-design-pattern-in-javascript.html) e [aqui](http://simplesideias.com.br/design-patterns-no-javascript-singleton)), mas se você tem o controle do código, basta definir um padrão de acesso se segui-lo por todo o desenvolvimento. Não existe técnica que o salve de não seguir seu próprio *design*, então não gaste muito tempo protegendo seu código de você mesmo.

Por outro lado, para a criação de bibliotecas, frameworks e APIs a história é outra.

Comment: Em Java há também a cláusula '*static*', que impede a instanciação da classe sem necessariamente ter que se fazer o construtor privado ou protegido.

Comment: "não gaste muito tempo protegendo seu código de você mesmo" excelente conselho, uma coisa é você tornar mais difícil os erros acidentais (por você mesmo ou por sua equipe), outra é querer tornar o código "à prova de idiotas". Existem limites pro que pode ser feito para proteger o código (mesmo em se tratando de APIs), é melhor fazer o que parece razoável e deixar o resto solto (i.e. concordo com sua sugestão de usar uma global, opcionalmente "congelando" o objeto e/ou a referência para evitar modificações acidentais, e não se preocupar com subclasses).

Comment: Verdade, novamente +1 pelas ótimas sugestões. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira Faz tempo que não mexo com Java, isso é uma característica nova da linguagem? (v6 pra frente) Eu conheço as classes **internas** `static` - que não tem nada a ver com restrições a instanciação - mas nada parecido com o que você está descrevendo. Tem alguma refência que você poderia me indicar? Estou curioso...

Comment: @LuizVieira Talvez você esteja confundindo com `abstract`.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Hum, desculpe, você tem razão. O jeito Java de se fazer a classe ser estática é tornar todos os atributos e métodos estáticos. Existe a cláusula 'abstract', que também impede a instanciação.

Comment: @utluiz Exatamente. :) Por favor, desculpe.

Comment: Eu editei a questão para trocar "estático" por "abstrato". Acho que faz mais sentido, mesmo as respostas tendo considerado a intenção de fazer classes estáticas.

Comment: @mgibsonbr: é em C# que você pode ter [classes estáticas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-Br/library/79b3xss3.aspx).

Comment: ... no entanto, [não acho](http://codecrafter.blogspot.ca/2009/09/c-static-classes-are-not-real-classes.html) que fazê-las classes foi uma boa idéia...

Answer (score 3):

Uma forma de se construir uma "classe" abstrata, com a usual herança de protótipos em Javascript, é usando um construtor como o seguinte:

```
/**
 * Construtor da classe abstrata.
 * @abstract
 * @constructor
 */
var Base = function() {
    if (this.constructor === Base) {
      throw new Error("Não pode instanciar classe abstrata!");
    }

    // .... código do construtor
};
```

O construtor checa se ele foi chamado diretamento (como em `new Base()`) com a propriedade [`constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor), e lança uma exceção caso isso aconteceu.

Essa "classe" só pode ser usada se for derivada:

```
/**
 * Construtor da classe derivada.
 * @constructor
 */
var Derived = function() {
    Base.apply(this, arguments);
};

Derived.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);
Derived.prototype.constructor = Derived;
```

A classe derivada chama o construtor da classe base com `apply`, e cria seu protótipo baseado no da classe base com `Object.create`. Também é muito importante atribuir o construtor corretamente para `Derived`, senão você não conseguirá criar instâncias de `Derived`.

Um exemplo mais extenso pode ser encontrado [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/yrJ5x/3/).

Note o uso do JSDoc [`@abstract`](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-abstract.html).

Comment: Se entendi bem, isso só faz sentido se é necessário ter alguma lógica no construtor, correto? Caso contrário, o efeito é o mesmo de utilizar um objeto literal (que lança exceção em tentativas de instanciação, e pode ser estendido).

Comment: @bfavaretto: não só isso, essa solução também mantém consistência entre as "classes". Todas são codificadas de forma semelhante, com construtores e protótipos. E é claro, mesmo se você não tiver lógica no construtor de `Base`, você pode adicioná-la depois sem ter que alterar `Derived`.